# How to override func of an existing go package?

Tags: go

I am new to go and cannot really put my head around it. 
I want to override a func in an existing package in go "log4go" on every log4go.Error("An error") call. What is the best way to do it? If I want to enhance an existing method, what else could be the way? Please bear if its a basic question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply cannot do this. There is no "best way" to do something impossible.

All you have are alternatives:

- Fork log4go and patch it.
- Do not use `log4go.Error` but your own wrapper `myError` which wraps around log4go's Error function.
- Redesign or look for a different logging package.

Comment: So instead of forking and patching it, I cannot even decorate the package?? Like add some new func's to it??

Comment: As I said: No you can't.

Comment: @infantDev to be able to do this, packages would have to be [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) (short: be able to treat them as values), which they are not. So you can't, at least not in pure go.