# golang how to override http package method?

Tags: go

I would like to override below method(in request.go) to apply escape string (eg: template.HTMLEscapeString(r.FormValue("some_param")).

I want to override because I do not want to escape on every FormValue calling.

Is there a way to do so?

```
func (r *Request) FormValue(key string) string{
    if r.Form == nil {
        r.ParseMultipartForm(defaultMaxMemory)
    }
    if vs := r.Form[key]; len(vs) > 0 {
        return vs[0]
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Go does not support method overloading.

Comment: To me the most simple way is just use a function `EscapeParse(req, param)`. But sure you can wrap the request and write a middle ware to convert the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override func of an existing go package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510088/how-to-override-func-of-an-existing-go-package)

Answer (score 7):

You can't override anything in Go.

The simplest solution here is to define a small helper function along the lines of:

```
func EscapeFormValue(req *http.Request, key string) string {
    return template.HTMLEscapeString(req.FormValue(key))
}
```

However, if you really want a custom struct with the same method, you can use [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) to wrap the `http.Request` and use the new wrapped type:

```
type newReq struct {
    *http.Request
}

func (n *newReq) FormValue(key string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("value: %s", n.Request.FormValue(key))
}

func main() {
    req := &http.Request{Method: "GET"}
    req.URL, _ = url.Parse("http://www.google.com/search?q=foo&q=bar")
    n := newReq{req}
    fmt.Println(n.FormValue("q"))
}
```

This outputs:

```
value: foo
```

Note that this only works because we are using `newReq` itself. Anything (including the http package) operating on a `http.Request` will want the embedded struct and will not see `newReq.FormValue`. This is what makes it **different from overriding**.